# JMeter: remote test with file upload

Tags: web-services, jmeter

My JMeter test should upload a file to a web service.

The upload request contains the Username and the filename in the Header.
The Username and the filename are listed in a CSV file.

On my local machine the jmx file, the csv file and all test data are in the same directory.
The test works great here.

However, if I start the test remote, the remote machine uses the correct username and filename but won't find the file because it's obviously not in JMeter's BaseDir.

Is there a best practice to send the test data to the remote server or do I have to manually put them there in the right directory every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter sends only .jmx test plan in form of [HashTree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html) to the remote machines. It is also possible to pass some [JMeter properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to remote engines via [`-G` command line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

Apart from this, remote JMeter engines are absolutely independent, if your test explicitly relies on an external file (.csv file used in the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or other file, which will be used for uploading)- you need to copy this file to all remote engines (manually or in automated manner), JMeter isn't smart enough to do this for you.